# ASP.Net Core Web Api access-control-max-age not being sent in the response header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

I have the SetPreFlightMaxAge in the Startup.cs. But the chrome Inspect > Network tab doesn't show it in the Response Headers.

Startup.cs

```
app.UseCors(o =>
{
o.WithOrigins(allowedDomains.ToArray())
.SetPreFlightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowCredentials()
});
```

Response Headers (GET method):
In addition to some other headers it sends these headers. There is a max-age in the third line below, but that's not the 10 mins value set in the Startup.cs

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: ...
set-cookie: ...
strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000
vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
```

Response Headers (OPTIONS method):

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: ...
access-control-allow-origin: ...
set-cookie: ...
```

Comment: Please provide more codes of Startup.cs. The call to `UseCors` must be placed after `UseRouting`, but before `UseAuthorization`.

Comment: Have u try request with different origins to test `Cors`  without `SetPreFlightMaxAge` ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm hosting a .NET Core 3.1 Web Api. This url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#preflight-requests shows 3 requirements the client requests must contain, or not contain to make it work. Have you seen them?

Answer (score 7):

In .NET core 3.1 try adding it in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("xyzpolicy", builder =>
            {
  
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
            }));
```

They say its [caped to 2 hours](https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/cache-your-cors/#cors-caching-for-browsers) for Chromium-based browsers